# Call a function on element ID click with selectors [Meteor + React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a small Blaze **event** handling as below;

```
Template.navigation.events({
    // Collapse menu in mobile mode after click on element
    'click #side-menu a:not([href$="\\#"])': function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 769) {
            $("body").toggleClass("show-sidebar");
        }
    }
});
```

UI looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <aside id="menu">
          <div id="navigation">
              <ul className="nav" id="side-menu">
              </ul>
          </div>
      </aside>
    )
  }
}
```

I just to convert the Blaze event to React function, so that all works same in React as it is working in Blaze Event handling.

The answer might be simple, but I am a newbie to React (16.2) so I expect soft corner.

Comment: `click #side-menu a:not([href$="\\#"])` Does that read as: add a click event to all anchor elements inside the #side-menu container that doesn't have a `#` as it's href attribute?

Comment: Yeah! That is it